# Unsigned char * data as return type of a function in c++ or c

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, clr, return-type

I am using visual studio 2010 with CLR(Common language Run Time).
I want to return unsigned char * from compress function to main function but both unsigned char * and  char * giving erro

"Error  7   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'char *' to 'unsigned char *'    F:\4-2\Thesis\PROJECT\Database Compression Main\Database Compression 2\db_comp_main.cpp 21 "

```
unsigned char* compressor(char *data)
{
    unsigned char *compressed_string;
    //With some process I had compressed string of data variable as unsigned char* in variable compressed_string successfully and also printed here. Now want to return it from here.
    return compressed_string;
}
int main()
{ 
  unsigned char *main_data; 
  main_data=compressor("Muhammad Ashikuzzaman.Student from Khulna University Of Engineering And Technology from Bangladesh");// When I click the error from error list the cursor is put here beside str by visual studio.
  printf("%s",main_data);
}
```

Need to return unsigned char * type data from compressor function. Please help.

Comment: Cast is explicitly required since you are using C ++ the compiler. Or change to the C compiler with options (`/TC`).

Comment: @Josh that is about actual and formal parameter type but I am calling about return type. Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change any of the data type (function argument `*data` or local variable `*main_data`) to match the type. Try this

```
unsigned char *main_data;
```

Or....

Simple type casting will work to make it working anyway:

```
unsigned char* compressor(char *data)
{
    unsigned char *compressed_string;
    compressed_string = (unsigned char*) data;
    return compressed_string;
}
int main()
{
  char *main_data;
  main_data=(char*) compressor("Muhammad Ashikuzzaman.Student from Khulna University Of Engineering And Technology from Bangladesh");
  printf("%s",main_data);
}
```

Or...

(Changing everything with `char*`)

There are three char types: (plain) `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`. Any `char` is usually an 8-bit integer* (There's no dedicated "character type" in C language) and in that sense, a `signed` and `unsigned char` have a useful meaning (generally equivalent to `uint8_t` and `int8_t`). When used as a character in the sense of text, use a `char` (also referred to as a plain char). This is typically a `signed char` but can be implemented either way by the compiler. So I think using `char*` is safe here.

Working Example (considering `char *` as data type):

```
char* compressor(char *data)
{
    char *compressed_string;
    compressed_string = "compressed";
    // compressed_string = data;
    return compressed_string;
}
int main()
{ 
  char *main_data; 
  main_data=compressor("Muhammad Ashikuzzaman.Student from Khulna University Of Engineering And Technology from Bangladesh");
  printf("%s",main_data);
}
```

Also, for simplicity you can use *pointer to pointer*

```
void compressor(char **data) {
    *data = "compressed"; // assuming the compressed data will be smaller in length of main data, so buffer overflow won't occur  
}

int main() {
    char *main_data = "Muhammad Ashikuzzaman.Student from Khulna University Of Engineering And Technology from Bangladesh";
    compressor(&main_data);
    printf("%s", main_data);
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**

As you asked an alternative to pass by reference, There is no way except *pass by reference* regarding passing array as function argument. Because when you will write `void func(char str[])` you may think you're performing *pass by value*. But g++ compiler will optimize the statement as `void func(char &str[0])` to avoid coping the whole array as function parameter. So in all scenario, you are actually passing by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to allocate the memory storage for the string. The pointer only point address a not any sequence of byte like array.You have to use calloc or malloc for C and new for C++ to allocate the required memory address. use typecasting to convert the char* to unsigned char*.

```
#include <bits\stdc++.h>
unsigned char* compressor(unsigned char *data)
{
    unsigned char *compressed_string = new unsigned char[100];
    //With some process I had compressed string of data variable as unsigned unsigned char** in variable compressed_string successfully and also printed here. Now want to return it from here.
    compressed_string = (unsigned char*)"working";
    return compressed_string;
}
int main()
{
  unsigned char *main_data = new unsigned char[1000];
  main_data=compressor((unsigned char*)"Muhammad Ashikuzzaman.Student from Khulna University Of Engineering And Technology from Bangladesh");// When I click the error from error list the cursor is put here beside str by visual studio.
  printf("%s",main_data);
}
```

you can use memory as required using a different input variable to avoid unnecessary dynamic allocation.

```
#include <bits\stdc++.h>
unsigned char* compressor(unsigned char *data) {
    unsigned char *compressed_string = new unsigned char[strlen((char*)data)+1];
    //With some process I had compressed string of data variable as unsigned char* in variable compressed_string successfully and also printed here. Now want to return it from here.
    compressed_string = (unsigned char*)"working";
    return compressed_string;
}
int main() {
    unsigned char *inp = new unsigned char[1000];
    inp = (unsigned char*)"Muhammad Ashikuzzaman.Student from Khulna University Of Engineering And Technology from Bangladesh";
    unsigned char *main_data = new unsigned char[strlen((char*)inp)+1];
    main_data = compressor(inp);
    printf("%s",main_data);
}
```

Comment: heavy memory leaked code and unnecessary dynamic allocation.